# Derivation of Modified Newton Method

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I have been stuck on this question for quite some time, and can't seem to figure the right piece of information given other sources on the internet primarily due to notational differences.

This is for the case of multiple roots, specifically
$$m = 2$$

I am currently at the following step:
$$e_{n+1} = x_{n+1} - r = e_n - 2 \cdot \frac{f(r)+f'(r)e_n+\frac{1}{2}f''(r)e_n^2+\frac{1}{6}f'''(\xi_n)e^3_n}{f'(r)+f''(r)e_n+\frac{1}{2}f'''(\zeta_n)e^2_n}$$

I'm supposed to end up with something on the form of:
$$e_{n+1} = \bigg(\frac{[]}{[]}\bigg)e_n^2$$

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does the multiplicity tell you about f and its derivatives at the root?

Comment: I assume you mean knowledge of $$f(r)=f'(r)=0, f''(r)\neq 0$$, however my main concern regards the last entries of the function. I don't see the argument for the xi and zeta?

Comment: Those are just unknown numbers, you don't need to think of them as functions (though actually they are functions of $x_n$). You don't need to know what numbers they are in order to carry out this asymptotic computation.

Comment: So I can think of them as constants? ie. I can write:
$$e_{n+1} = e_n - 2 \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{2}f''(r)e_n^2+\frac{1}{6}f'''(\xi_n)e^3_n}{f''(r)e_n+\frac{1}{2}f'''(\zeta_n)e^2_n}$$ by inserting the aforementioned (and presumed agreed upon?) knowledge of multiplicity m given f and its derivatives at the root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hint to get you moving: once you substitute $f(r)=0,f'(r)=0,f''(r) \neq 0$ (which is what it means that $r$ is a root of $f$ with multiplicity $m=2$) you have

$$e_{n+1}=e_n - \frac{f''(r) e_n^2 + \frac{1}{3} f'''(\xi_n) e_n^3}{f''(r) e_n + \frac{1}{2} f'''(\zeta_n) e_n^2}.$$

Now get a common denominator between these two terms and you should see several terms cancel. Note here $\xi_n$ and $\zeta_n$ are just unknown numbers; they depend on $x_n$, but not in a way that you can or need to resolve. Instead you will just replace the associated terms with a bound on $|f'''|$.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance! The bound on $$|f'''|$$, what am I missing? Is the bound 1, as we go to the extreme of the failure being 1? I have tried your hint and gained the following, I hope you can be patient with me:

Comment: (Apparently my latex writing skills were too slow to add to the comment above)

$$e_{n+1} = e_n - \frac{2e_n(f'''(\xi_n)e_n+3f''(r))}{3f'''(\zeta_n)e_n+6f''(r)} = e^2\bigg(\frac{3f'''(\zeta_n)-2f'''(\xi_n)}{3f'''(\zeta_n)e_n+6f''(r)}\bigg)$$

Comment: @Anon2312 That looks...mostly right? It's not how I would've done the algebra, so I'm not sure it's *exactly* right.

Comment: I got caught up in confusion with the algebraic derivation, so I tried to put it into Maple with arbitrary names for the derivatives, but so they were unique. So basically as if they were different constants.
However, I am not sure how exactly the bound on the unknown numbers helps me simplify the statement

Comment: @Anon2312 Fair enough. I think the intuition is perhaps best captured by moving $e_n$'s around until the fraction looks like $\frac{1+h_1}{1+h_2}$. So here that means you pull out $f''(r) e_n^2$ from the top and $f''(r) e_n$ from the bottom, leaving you with $e_n - e_n \frac{1+h_1}{1+h_2}$. Then that fraction is close to $1$, in particular it deviates from $1$ by an amount of order $e_n$.